# Joining DataFrames to update a value in original

Tags: python, pandas, merge

prev_staff DataFrame contains emails and a true/false flag. I would like to update this flag with another DataFrame that contains a sub-list of emails and a flag all set to true. 
I'm looking for a more efficient way to update the column value without having to drop and rename columns from the resulting merge. 
The original column is lunchable but the merge generates a lunchable_x and y and I would like to avoid having to manage that.

```
new_staff = pd.merge(prev_staff,new_staff_emails, on='email',how='left')
new_staff['lunchable_x'] = new_staff['lunchable_y']
new_staff = new_staff.drop(columns=['lunchable_y'])
new_staff =  new_staff.rename(columns={'lunchable_x': 'lunchable'})
new_staff['lunchable'].fillna('false', inplace=True)
new_staff.to_csv(path + 'staff.csv')
```

> new_staff columns

```
Index(['user_id', 'name', 'email', 'start_date', 'table', 'team', 'specialty',
       'lunchable', 'previous_lunches'],
      dtype='object')
```

> new_staff_emails columns

```
Index(['email', 'lunchable'], dtype='object')
```

> prev_staff columns

```
Index(['user_id', 'name', 'email', 'start_date', 'table', 'team', 'specialty',
       'lunchable', 'previous_lunches'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: can you include headers of prev_staff and new_staff_emails?

Comment: Instead of merging here could you just set the value of `lunchable` in `prev_staff` to `True` if the email is in `new_staff`?

Comment: How would you suggest doing this, other than merging?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Can you please provide a [MCVE] ?

Comment: so what you want if to update your previous staff's emails with the contents of new_staff and preserve all columns except the duplicate generated by the merge, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of joining you can directly set the value of `lunchable` in `new_staff` with the following:

```
new_staff.loc[new_staff["email"].isin(prev_staff["email"]), "lunchable"] = True
```

This code will set `new_staff["lunchable"] = True` for all emails in `new_staff` that are also in `prev_staff`.

Comment: This is good. What is the performance impact of using isin vs merge? Would you use the same approach over millions of rows?

Comment: In my opinion, if you're going to `fillna(False)` straight afterwards, you might as well directly assign the Boolean series.

Answer (score 2):

According to your explanation, it seems as if you don't need to use merge since this flag is set to true for all records in the new table. Using np.where should work just fine. (But feel free to let me know if I misunderstood your question)

```
new_staff = prev_staff.copy()
new_staff['lunchable'] = np.where(new_staff['emials'].isin(list(new_staff_emails.email.unique())),'True',new_staff['lunchable'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign a series of Boolean values:

```
new_staff['lunchable'] = new_staff['email'].isin(prev_staff['email'].unique())
```

Your new series will consist of `True` or `False` values depending on whether each email address exists in `prev_staff['email']`.

Direct assignment will be more efficient than `merge`, as it does not involve the creation of a new dataframe.